# Where can I find source code for itertools.combinations() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find a way to write a combination function. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

See in the documentation of [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). There is an equivalent code for this function:

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(r)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Comment: how does this actually work? I'm trying to comprehend + I'm missing something. The `indices` array tells which elements of the pool are used, but I can't seem to figure out how it generates sets of indices that don't include repeats.

Comment: @JasonS, a few points: First, notice from the examples, that the algorithm generates tuples with `indices` always sorted (specifically `indices[i] < indices[i+1]` which doesn't allow repeats) and the right-most dimensions  updated fastest.  To get the next tuple, the for-loop over `i` finds the furthest right position in `indices` that can be incremented. If no such `i` is found (so no `break` happens), the `else` clause of the for-loop is triggered and we're done. Otherwise, `index[i]` is incremented and the loop over `j` resets the later indices to count up from the new `index[i]`.

Comment: @JasonS I am confused about the else: return statement. What is the indentation there. When is executed, what the if corresponding to this else?

Comment: @MaPy the `else` after the `for` loop can be thought of mentally as a hypothetical "nobreak" keyword. In other words, the `for` loop could have exited via the enclosed `break` or by the `for` loop range having been consumed(`StopIteration`). There is often the expectation that a `break` in a `for` loop is hit at some point through execution, and if it never was, to react differently. The `for else` allows `else` to execute in the event `break` never is.

Comment: @eumiro This answer is misleading and doesn't answer the question of where the source code for itertools is. It's not clearly stated that the Python shown here is not the actual itertools source, which is written in C, but instead is a Python translation for documentation/illustrative purposes. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5731578/6243352)

Answer (score 46):

The actual source code is written in C and can be found in the file [`itertoolsmodule.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c).

Answer (score 1):

The provided code in the accepted answer needs some edit and the edit queue is full. Here is the updated version of the rough equivalent in python from the [itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
def combinations(iterable, r):
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Answer (score 0):

The while loop solution may be quite confusing... I wrote an "easier-to-understand" code using recursion. For every decision we make, we need to make more decisions until the combination reaches the length we desire (base case). Following is the code for itertools.combinations but considering that permutation is just an order-sensitive version of combinations, you can remove the sorting and hashset and easily make it an itertools.permuations method.

```
def combinations(curr, result, used):
    if len(curr) == l:
        result.add(tuple(sorted(curr))) #Modify this line to change it into itertools.permutations
        return
    else:
        for i in arr:
            if len(curr) == 0:
                check_set = set()
            else:
                check_set = used
            if i not in used:
                temp = curr + [i]
                check_set.add(i)
                combinations(temp, result, check_set)
```