# find the number of pairs of elements such that their sum add up to 8, Array is a=[3, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 3]

Tags: python, pointers

My code is not running, please debug it. I am getting error as Index out of range in line (a[i+1]==a[i]) but i never reaches n-1
Please correct this code and remove the error. Answer is 4

```
a=[3, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 3]

a=sorted(a)
m=0
if(a[0]>=8):
    print(0)
else:
    for i in range(7):
        if(a[i]>8):
            break

    a=a[0:i+1]
    n=len(a)
    i=0
    j=n-1
    x=0
    y=0
    while(i!=j or i<j):
        if((a[i]+a[j])>8):
            j=j-1
        elif(a[i]+a[j]==8):
            if(a[j-1]==a[j]):
                j=j-1
                x=x+1
            else:

                if(a[i+1]==a[i]):
                    i=i+1
                    y=y+1
                else:
                    x=x+1
                    y=y+1
                    m=m+x*y
                    x=0
                    y=0
                    i=i+1
                    j=j-1
        else:
            i=i+1
    print(m)
```

Comment: I'm afraid your code looks extremely overly complex, even if not using any external packages.  Honestly I would start again and try to reduce the complexity.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> sum(a.count(8 - a.pop()) for _ in a[:])
4
```

Comment: Clever... I like it, though it may have some bugs if duplicates are important.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Not sure what you mean. Their example already has duplicates.

Comment: Damn this is good.

Comment: This one has duplicates. But if duplicates are not allowed then the answer will be wrong. See Chrises output in his answer. Overall good answer.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Well OP says answer is 4, so apparently they are allowed, no?

Comment: My comment was more for future readers of the question/answer.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse Hmm, but then you can say that for *many* questions/answers. And I wouldn't call it a "bug" if it doesn't solve some *other* problem :-)

Comment: Thanks for your time everyone, I am able to debug the code,
an error was due to while(i !=j or i<j).
the correct is while(i<j)

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import combinations
a=[3, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1, 3]

# To eliminate duplicates
set(x for x in combinations(a,2) if sum(x) == 8)

# To keep duplicates
list(x for x in combinations(a,2) if sum(x) == 8)
```

Output:

```
{(3, 5), (5, 3), (6, 2)}
[(3, 5), (5, 3), (5, 3), (6, 2)]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply;
but using any package is not allowed in my homework

Comment: @anadi then write the [equivalent code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5731531/8150685).